# How do I save the captured image of a signature to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a script that captures a signature on a touch screen and saves it as an image, I can't figure out how to then submit that image to MySQL. Do I need to add the name tag to the image and use that as the variable or can I use the id tag as the variable? I know how to upload an image to a folder on the server and save the path to the image in MySQL, I'm just not sure how to save this image!
Here is my 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JzKhS/3/)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script src="signature/todataurl.js"></script>
        <script src="signature/signature.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
<center>
        <div id="canvas">
            <canvas class="roundCorners" id="newSignature"
            style="position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #c4caac; left: 0px; top: 0px;" height="124" width="524"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script>
            signatureCapture();
        </script>
<br/><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="signatureSave()">
            Save signature
        </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="signatureClear()">
            Clear signature
        </button>
        <br/>
        Saved Image
        <br/>
        <img id="saveSignature" alt="Saved image png"/>
</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
    function signatureCapture() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 276;
    canvas.height = 180;
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.strokeStyle = "#444";
    context.lineWidth = 1.5;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var disableSave = true;
    var pixels = [];
    var cpixels = [];
    var xyLast = {};
    var xyAddLast = {};
    var calculate = false;
    {   //functions
        function remove_event_listeners() {
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

            document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
        }

        function get_coords(e) {
            var x, y;

            if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
                var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
                var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;

                x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
                y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
            } else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
                x = e.layerX;
                y = e.layerY;
            } else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
            }

            return {
                x : x,
                y : y
            };
        };

        function on_mousedown(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);

            empty = false;
            var xy = get_coords(e);
            context.beginPath();
            pixels.push('moveStart');
            context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
            pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
            xyLast = xy;
        };

        function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var xy = get_coords(e);
            var xyAdd = {
                x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
                y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
            };

            if (calculate) {
                var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
                var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
                pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
            } else {
                calculate = true;
            }

            context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
            xyAddLast = xyAdd;
            xyLast = xy;

        };

        function on_mouseup(e) {
            remove_event_listeners();
            disableSave = false;
            context.stroke();
            pixels.push('e');
            calculate = false;
        };
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
}

function signatureSave() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;
};

function signatureClear() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

and here is the todataurl.js code:

```
    Number.prototype.toUInt=function(){ return this<0?this+4294967296:this; };

Number.prototype.bytes32=function(){ return [(this>>>24)&0xff,(this>>>16)&0xff,(this>>>8)&0xff,this&0xff]; };

Number.prototype.bytes32sw=function(){ return [this&0xff,(this>>>8)&0xff,(this>>>16)&0xff,(this>>>24)&0xff]; };

Number.prototype.bytes16=function(){ return [(this>>>8)&0xff,this&0xff]; };

Number.prototype.bytes16sw=function(){ return [this&0xff,(this>>>8)&0xff]; };



Array.prototype.adler32=function(start,len){

        switch(arguments.length){ case 0:start=0; case 1:len=this.length-start; }

        var a=1,b=0;

        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){

                a = (a+this[start+i])%65521; b = (b+a)%65521;

        }

        return ((b << 16) | a).toUInt();

};



Array.prototype.crc32=function(start,len){

        switch(arguments.length){ case 0:start=0; case 1:len=this.length-start; }

        var table=arguments.callee.crctable;

        if(!table){

                table=[];

                var c;

                for (var n = 0; n < 256; n++) {

                        c = n;

                        for (var k = 0; k < 8; k++)

                                c = c & 1?0xedb88320 ^ (c >>> 1):c >>> 1;

                        table[n] = c.toUInt();

                }

                arguments.callee.crctable=table;

        }

        var c = 0xffffffff;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)

                c = table[(c ^ this[start+i]) & 0xff] ^ (c>>>8);



        return (c^0xffffffff).toUInt();

};





(function(){

        var toDataURL=function(){

                var imageData=Array.prototype.slice.call(this.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height).data);

                var w=this.width;

                var h=this.height;

                var stream=[

                        0x89,0x50,0x4e,0x47,0x0d,0x0a,0x1a,0x0a,

                        0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0d,0x49,0x48,0x44,0x52

                ];

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, w.bytes32() );

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, h.bytes32() );

                stream.push(0x08,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00);

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(12,17).bytes32() );

                var len=h*(w*4+1);

                for(var y=0;y<h;y++)

                        imageData.splice(y*(w*4+1),0,0);

                var blocks=Math.ceil(len/32768);

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, (len+5*blocks+6).bytes32() );

                var crcStart=stream.length;

                var crcLen=(len+5*blocks+6+4);

                stream.push(0x49,0x44,0x41,0x54,0x78,0x01);

                for(var i=0;i<blocks;i++){

                        var blockLen=Math.min(32768,len-(i*32768));

                        stream.push(i==(blocks-1)?0x01:0x00);

                        Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, blockLen.bytes16sw() );

                        Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, (~blockLen).bytes16sw() );

                        var id=imageData.slice(i*32768,i*32768+blockLen);

                        Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, id );

                }

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, imageData.adler32().bytes32() );

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(crcStart, crcLen).bytes32() );



                stream.push(0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x49,0x45,0x4e,0x44);

                Array.prototype.push.apply(stream, stream.crc32(stream.length-4, 4).bytes32() );

                return "data:image/png;base64,"+btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,stream));

        };



        var tdu=HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL;



        HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL=function(type){



                        var res=tdu.apply(this,arguments);

                        if(res.substr(0,6)=="data:,"){

                                HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL=toDataURL;

                                return this.toDataURL();

                        }else{

                                HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL=tdu;

                                return res;

                        }

        }



})();
```

Comment: This is what I would suggest: Upload image to some directory on your server and give it some random name and store the path to image in your mySql table. Otherwise, having stored image data in table will increase the size of table. May be more experts can comment on this.

Comment: @blunderboy Did you read my question? I said I know how to upload an image to the server and store the path to the image in the database, that's not the problem I am having!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

submit image data that you get from your canvas using AJAX:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    type: "POST",
    data: canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {...},
    error: function (jqxhr, status, error) {...}
});
```

Comment: Sorry I had to mark this unanswered and added code to an additional javascript that I was missing. So I'm not sure where I would add your suggestion to my code!

Comment: maybe `signatureSave` function?